# La siguiente función de jQuery me cierra el modal en el segundo click

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Actualmente, la siguiente función me cierra el modal una vez que ejecuto un segundo click dentro del mismo, debería poder ser en el primer intento. Que estaría mal ?

```
$('#gropu').click(function() {

    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $(".itemcito").removeClass("opcionActiva") ;

});
```

Comment: Amigo, por favor se mas específico con tu problema y coloca el código del modal, de tus funciones que lo abren y cierran y de todo lo que tenga que ver. Por favor, tambien lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

//Prueba añadiendole el `on` antes de ejecutar el evento click

```
$('#gropu').on('click', ()=>{

  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $(".itemcito").removeClass("opcionActiva") ;

});
```